# My Scrapy item['img_urls'] doesn't download the file

Tags: python, image, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm currently working on a student's data scientist project which consist of building a fish recognition system by picture. We will use tensorflow to make sense from data & scrapy to find a massive amount of data (fish picture & his scientific name).

I'm new to scrapy, but I've been working a lot since 3 days, I 've written a basic fishbase spider (you'll find the url in the spider's code):

```
import scrapy
from ..items import FishbaseItem

class FishbaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'fishbase'
    allowed_domains = ['fishbase.org']
    start_urls = [
        'http://fishbase.org/ListByLetter/ScientificNamesQ.htm',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        all_fish = response.xpath('//tbody/tr')
        for fish in all_fish:
            taxo = fish.xpath('td/a/i/text()').extract()
            fish_url = fish.xpath('td/a/@href').extract_first()

            item = FishbaseItem()
            item['taxonomy'] = taxo

            r=scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(fish_url),callback=self.parseFish)
            r.meta['item'] = item
            yield r

    def parseFish(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        imgUrl = response.xpath('//div/span/div/a/img/@src').extract_first()
        item['img_urls'] = response.urljoin(imgUrl)
        yield item
```

Here is the item file :

```
import scrapy
class FishbaseItem(scrapy.Item):
    taxonomy = scrapy.Field()
    fish_url = scrapy.Field()
    img_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

and the setting file :

```
BOT_NAME = 'fishbase'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['fishbase.spiders']

NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'fishbase.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = 'tmp/images/'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

I'm getting the results I want, but the images won't download. I don't understand why... Plus, I've downloaded a buck of images from other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- As per the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline), the item field should be `image_urls`, not `img_urls` (unless you override the `IMAGES_URLS_FIELD` setting).
- The value should be a list of URLs, not a string (single URL). Currently you store just a single URL with line `item['img_urls'] = response.urljoin(imgUrl)`.